# Date of birth gives 13 november 1972 instead of 14 november 1972

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have import data from my Excel-list to a SharePoint List. In my list I have data from employees (including myself). One of the column is the date of birth. Only when my list is imported in SharePoint List. My birth date is suddenly "13 novembember 1972" instead of "14 novmenber 1972". And in the Excel list the date is giving correctly. What can i solve this?

Gr. p

Comment: Difference maybe because of the regional time settings of your SharePoint site. Play with the settings and see if it helps to solve your issue.